# MongoDB: Check if value is null or the array is empty

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to match all documents that don't contain the "Company" attribute or where the "Company" value is null or an empty array.

```
User.find({Company: {$in: [null, [] ]}}, function (err, users) {
      if (err) { throw err; }
      console.log(users.length);

}).then(function(doc) {
      console.log("finish User Company");
});
```

Comment: Funny enough `{$in: [null, [] ]}` works for me using mongo driver, but does not with mongoose.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) query operator with a check for each condition:

```
{
  $or: [{
    // Check about no Company key
    Company: {
       $exists: false
    }
  }, {
    // Check for null
    Company: null
  }, {
    // Check for empty array
    Company: {
       $size: 0
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Trying this myself and even with an index on `Company`, this query will do a COLLSCAN, not ideal

Comment: @NBcrafts The `$size` operator doesn't use indexes, so that's why. Maybe swapping out that last condition for `{"Company.0":{$exists:false}}` would use the index?

Comment: You can collapse the first two into `{Company:null}` since that matches both null and missing fields.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I think I ended up using {"array.0": {$exists:false}}, not sure, this was a while back. Thank you though good info for whoever looks at this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following

```
db.test.find({
  "Company.0": {
      $exists: false
  }
})
```

It will take care of (all the conditions that you asked for):

1. Company:[]
2. Company: null
3. Company attribute missing.

It will not care of:

1. Company:[null,]

Note, here the 0th index is present though it is null.

Answer (score 0):

to display null or missing values in the array, use `$map` and `$cond`

```
  {$map:   { 
      input: {$cond: [ {$eq:[ "$field1.field2.value", [] ] }, [], "$field1"]}, 
      as: "check55", 
      in: "$$check55.field2.value"
   }},
```

Hope this helps---pradeep