# How check for exist and empty in mongoose by find function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to check some field for empty. the field can be null or not exist or empty array.

I did so far something does work but not cover when the "exist" or "null":

```
.find({ roles: { '$size': 0 } }, { projection: {} });
```

one important thing, it must start with `.find({ roles:` . so I can't use `$or` [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379744/mongodb-check-if-value-is-null-or-the-array-is-empty). I need another solution for do it by pass a condition into roles object in find function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `$in`, [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fJUr6pZJAHE)

```
.find({
  roles: {
    $in: [null, 0, []]
  }
})
```

The [not exist and null value](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/) only, you can try, [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_Mpd5Zj3Syn)

```
.find({
  roles: null
})
```

---